# Python script does not restart after it crashes

Tags: python, exception, crash, ioerror

I have a python script that is doing some stuff called "python1.py". Sometimes because connection issue, it crashes.  I have another script called "loop.py" that is supposed to monitor the first one when it crashes and restart it. So far, it fails to restart. Meaning, when an exception is risen ( IOError or WatsonException ( I am using a Watson API ) ) the script stops

python1.py is something like this :

```
def mainfunction ():
    a = randrange(0, 1)
    Print (' my routine is doing something')
    if a = 1 :
        Print ('a = 1 ')
    else :
        Print (' a is not equals to 1') 

mainfunction ()
```

The other script that is supposed to restart the first one is something like this :

```
def loopApp():
    while True :
        try:
            python1.mainfunction ()
        except IOError :
            print (' IOError y')
        except WatsonException :
            print (' Exception from watson API')

loopApp ()
```

python1.py should restart when every time the exceptions happens, but it is not.

Comment: There are a few problems with your script: (1) In `python1.py` the function is already called at import time without guarding `try` / `except`. Also there is no handling for any other exception than `IOError` and `WatsonException`.

Comment: Thinking of these as two separate scripts is probably confusing matters. One script isn't restarting the other script. There is a one time import from script one into script two. Then script two is running over and over.

Comment: You Recommand to put in one script only ? How should I proceed then ?

Comment: And Actually, the second script does not restart the first one after the first one crashes, and this is my problem. I want the first one to be automatically restarted once is crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way using python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). It works fine and I could get expections working.

```
def loopApp():
   
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        print ("wa_loop is starting")
        try:
            process = subprocess.call(['python', 'wa_dir_watch.py'])
        except 'IOError':
            print ("\nretrying after IOError")
            continue         
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print ("\nstopped by user Ctr+C")
            quit() 
            
loopApp()
```